# A Question About the Proof on Existence of Orthonormal Basis of a Nondegenerate Bilinear Form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

**Link**

[For non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form there is a basis $\{v'_i\}$ such that $B(v_i, v'_j) = \delta_{ij}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370647/for-non-degenerate-symmetric-bilinear-form-there-is-a-basis-v-i-such-that)

In the thread above, the proof is based on induction on the dimension of the vector space. However, I think that the induction is valid if you have shown that this bilinear form is also nondegenerate on the orthogonal complement of $\text{span}(x)$, which is the step I cannot think of the proof.

Comment: note: congruence does not change rank, so $\det(B)\neq 0\implies \det(G')\neq 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $x$ has $B(x,x)\neq 0$, then $V=Span(x)\oplus U$ where $U$ is the orthogonal complement of $Span(x)$. Suppose the form was degenerate on $U$ and let $v$ be a degenerate vector for the form on $U$. I claim that $v$ is degenerate on all of $V$. To see this note that by the direct sum decomposition above we can write any $w\in V$ as $tx+u$ where $u\in U$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Then we have

$$B(v,w)=B(v,tx+u)=tB(v,x)+B(v,u)=0$$

where the first term is zero becuase $v$ is in the orthogonal complement of $Span(x)$ and the second term is zero since $v$ is degenerate on $U$. Therefore if $B$ is non-degenerate on $V$ it is also non-degenerate on $U$.